# How to replace python-gtkhtml2?

Tags: 10.04, gedit

I would like to install under Lucid the [restructured text plugin for gedit](http://kib2.alwaysdata.net/GEdit/), but it fails as it can't import gtkhtml2. Previously it was provided by the python-gtkhtml2 package, but it's not compatible with python2.6.

Is there any recent package that is backwards compatible with gtkhtml2 and could be easily put in place of the old import line? Or any other solution you know?

Comment: This should have been reported as a bug. Vote to close =)

Answer (score 0):

Savvas Radevic (medigeek) wrote on 2010-06-13: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnochm/+bug/538773

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.